# Getting Twitter Timeline Fees to Show in IOS App

Tags: ios, twitter, ios6, twitter-oauth

is their any way to show twitter feeds/timeline from my account to ios app ? I want to use twiiter framework to display tweets. I have tried rest api 1.1 but it seems not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Twitter API to get your Timeline into *JSON format*.

More information about it : https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Then, you can parse the response using `NSDictionnary` methods.

I hope this can help you, for me is the best and simple way ;)

Comment: I have done using that and it works fine ,however as twitter feeds may have image and text and may only have text how to handle that in uitableview ? Any idea ?